# How can I retrieve the state of processed messages in Azure Service Bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

In our current application which we are migrating to Azure, we use a SQL Server table as a queue. The application needs to process files uploaded by users. For each upload we add a row to the table which has a state column (new, inprocess, successfully processed, failed processing) and the userid. By querying this table, we can easily show an user the state of each request. 
While migrating this solution to Azure, we are planning to use Azure Service Bus instead of a queue table. All file upload requests will be put in the queue and processed by a web job using ServiceBusTrigger. But my question is:
How can we query the state of all messages for a user?

From the documentation, I understand that we can query the state of messages which are currently in the queue and I can use the message metadata to filter for a userid, but how about messages which have already been processed?

Do I need to maintain a separate table for recording processing state of historic messages or does ServiceBus expose some API for this?

Comment: Do you need to have the state for each message or you present it into a dashboard (I.e.: number of proceeeded messages, number of failed messages) ?

Comment: I don't need aggregate queue-level statistics to show in a dashboard. I need the state of individual messages. The grid which I show each user has the following columns - RequestDate, State of Request (i.e. whether it is in process, successfully processed or failed). Hope this clarifies..

Comment: Yes, you definitively need to store these information as you will not be able to obtain it from ASB.

Comment: Thanks.. I will do it likewise then.. It is not very difficult to plonk in a separate table for this but it just adds one more component to the architecture and one more failure point, hence I wanted to be sure that ASB does not have this capability built in. Thanks again for your answer.